# Finding shortest routes from one point to all others?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst, routing

I have lat and long information for 234 locations and I have shapefile of the route network.

I am trying to obtain shortest path from each location to all other locations. For instance for location 1, I would like to find shortest path from location 1 to 2, location 1 to 3, location 1 to 4  ....... location 1 to 234.

I tried to do this in ArcMap with OD cost matrix but the output was a straight line . I would like to obtain routes like I obtain by using "new route analysis".

Is there a way to obtain routes instead of straight line in ArcMap, or by using python?

Comment: Look [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/types-of-network-analyses.htm) if you want the line then use Route analysis. You would automate this using modelbuilder and generate loops between the pairs of points. Alternatively, reading the help file, it says closest facility solver can also return the true line shape.

Comment: Can you please explain how I will generate loops ? I am new user for ArcMap @Hornbydd

Comment: Have a look at the help file and using a feature selection iterator in modelbuilder.